# "ant -p" does not show all targets

Tags: ant

I know that my build.xml contains at least ten targets, but only two show up when I run `ant -p`:

```
$ ant -p build.xml
Buildfile: /home/nico/myproject/build.xml

Main targets:

 clean  clean
Default target: deploy
```

How to display ALL targets?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ant -p` only shows targets that have a description.

To show ALL targets, run `ant -p -v`. This will generate quite a lot of lines, but the full list of targets is easily findable at the end of the output:

```
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on July 8 2015
Trying the default build file: build.xml
Buildfile: /home/nico/myproject/build.xml
Detected Java version: 1.7 in: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Detected OS: Linux
parsing buildfile /home/nico/myproject/build.xml with URI = file:/home/nico/myproject/build.xml
Project base dir set to: /home/nico/myproject
parsing buildfile jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/usr/share/ant/lib/ant.jar!/org/apache/tools/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
Importing file /home/nico/ide/build-common-portlet.xml from /home/nico/myproject/build.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile /home/nico/ide/build-common-portlet.xml with URI = file:/home/nico/ide/build-common-portlet.xml
Importing file /home/nico/ide/build-common-plugin.xml from /home/nico/ide/build-common-portlet.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile /home/nico/ide/build-common-plugin.xml with URI = file:/home/nico/ide/build-common-plugin.xml
Already defined in main or a previous import, ignore war
Importing file /home/nico/ide/build-common.xml from /home/nico/ide/build-common-plugin.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile /home/nico/ide/build-common.xml with URI = file:/home/nico/ide/build-common.xml
 [property] Loading Environment env.
parsing buildfile jar:file:/home/nico/ide/lib/ant-contrib.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/home/nico/ide/lib/ant-contrib.jar!/net/sf/antcontrib/antlib.xml from a zip file
parsing buildfile jar:file:/home/nico/ide/lib/antelopetasks.jar!/ise/antelope/tasks/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/home/nico/ide/lib/antelopetasks.jar!/ise/antelope/tasks/antlib.xml from a zip file
 [property] Loading /home/nico/ide/build.nico.properties
Property "env.COMPUTERNAME" has not been set
 [property] Loading /home/nico/ide/build.${env.COMPUTERNAME}.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /home/nico/ide/build.${env.COMPUTERNAME}.properties
Property "env.HOST" has not been set
 [property] Loading /home/nico/ide/build.${env.HOST}.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /home/nico/ide/build.${env.HOST}.properties
Property "env.HOSTNAME" has not been set
 [property] Loading /home/nico/ide/build.${env.HOSTNAME}.properties
 [property] Unable to find property file: /home/nico/ide/build.${env.HOSTNAME}.properties
 [property] Loading /home/nico/ide/build.properties
Override ignored for property "app.server.type"
Override ignored for property "app.server.tomcat.dir"
Override ignored for property "app.server.tomcat.portal.dir"
Override ignored for property "app.server.tomcat.deploy.dir"
Override ignored for property "app.server.tomcat.lib.global.dir"
Override ignored for property "app.server.parent.dir"
Importing file /home/nico/ide/build-common-ivy.xml from /home/nico/ide/build-common.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
parsing buildfile /home/nico/ide/build-common-ivy.xml with URI = file:/home/nico/ide/build-common-ivy.xml
[available] Found: /home/nico/ide/.ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar
parsing buildfile jar:file:/home/nico/ide/.ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml with URI = jar:file:/home/nico/ide/.ivy/ivy-2.3.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml from a zip file
[available] Unable to find ivy.xml
[available] Found: /home/nico/ide/ivy.xml
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
[whichresource] Searching for org/eclipse/jdt/core/JDTCompilerAdapter.class
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
[available] Found: docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties
 [property] Loading /home/nico/myproject/docroot/WEB-INF/liferay-plugin-package.properties
[antlib:ise.antelope.tasks] Could not load definitions from resource ise/antelope/tasks/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
Property "plugin.full.version" has not been set
Property "plugin.full.version" has not been set
Property "plugin.full.version" has not been set
Property "plugin.full.version" has not been set
Property "plugin.full.version" has not been set
[available] Unable to find src
[available] Unable to find tmp
 [macrodef] creating macro  classpath-to-jar
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper
Overriding previous definition of reference to ant.projectHelper

Main targets:

 clean  clean
Other targets:

 all
 build-client
 build-common-plugin.war
 build-css
 build-db
 build-lang
 build-lang-cmd
 build-service
 build-wsdd
 build-wsdl
 build-xsd
 clean-portal-dependencies
 compile
 compile-import-shared
 compile-java
 compile-test
 compile-test-cmd
 compile-test-integration
 compile-test-unit
 create
 deploy
 direct-deploy
 format-javadoc
 format-source
 format-wsdl
 format-xsd
 jar-javadoc
 jar-source
 javadoc
 merge
 merge-unzip
 patch
 print-current-time
 publish
 publish-local-m2-release
 publish-local-m2-snapshot
 publish-remote-m2-release
 publish-remote-m2-snapshot
 setup-eclipse
 setup-jrebel
 shrink-zip-cmd
 sort-xml-attributes
 test
 test-class
 test-cmd
 test-integration
 test-unit
 war
Default target: deploy
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, there is a simple answer.
The 'ant -p' command will only output targets that have a description set. 
For example:

```
<target name="target1" description="My first target">
```

I have always thought of this as a way to 'control' what targets are publicly visible, very much like Java uses public and private on methods, etc.

Comment: I don't have control over the build script, it is not maintained by me. The point of the question is to show all targets, not just those with a description.